# Combining Parent theme JS and CSS

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a parent theme for my website and a child theme. Currently i am using the child theme.
I have no plans in the future of updating the parent theme.

Is this a possibility? I combine all the CSS and JS of the parent theme into 1 file (1 for CSS and one for JS)? My child theme will have its own stylesheet where i will override parent styles and add new styles. This would be simply to speed up my website.

Plugins would have their own scripts and css as they will continue to receive updates.

Is this possible? And if it is, is there a place in the files in wordpress where all the stylesheets and javascript files are linked so that i can remove them and just place the links of the two files?

Forgive me, i am a total Noob at web development, and i am learning on the Job.

Comment: First off, are you sure that's a good starting point to starting optimizing your site? Measure performance first, figure out _why_ your site is slow and _then_ start fixing things.

Comment: This is usually done as a part of minifying your page's resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Is it possible? Yes, it is possible to combine/concatenate the parent theme's CSS and JSS files (you can use something like Grunt to handle this automatically). If your themes are enqueuing your CSS and JS correctly using `wp_enqueue_styles()` then you should have no issue adding and removing CSS and JS as required.

---

Long answer: Is it *advisable?* As with most things web-related then answer is *it depends.* If your child theme is also loading CSS and JS you're going to take a performance hit with each additional HTTP request that is being made. A lot of this boils down to *performance vs maintainability* - it's a question of balancing the two, as improving one usually hampers the other. Having each plugin and child theme load its own JS and CSS is better for maintainability as it encapsulates the dependancies of each component, but it sucks on a performance front. You should be asking yourself:

- Do I actually need a child theme?
- What CSS and JS (if any) should the parent theme load?
- What CSS and JS (if any) should the plugins be loading?

Personally, I'm a fan of trying to leave the active theme in charge of the visuals; this means that only the child theme loads CSS, and that CSS includes any styles that are required for plugins. Additionally I try to keep plugins as lightweight as possible so that they don't *need* to load any CSS; they simply take advantage of any existing styles that active theme has. If it's a third-party plugin I will often de-enqueue any CSS and let the theme handle it; this keeps the visuals consistent and removes the additional HTTP requests.

You need to consider your own requirements and make a decision from there.

Comment: that is a brilliant answer and you have given me a ton to think about.